# Difference between combinebykey and aggregatebykey

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am very new to Apache spark so this question might not be well to ask, but I am not getting the difference between `combinebykey` and `aggregatebykey` and when to use which operation.

Answer (score 5):

`aggregateByKey` takes an initial accumulator, a first lambda function to merge a value to an accumulator and a second lambda function to merge two accumulators.

`combineByKey` is more general and adds an initial lambda function to create the initial accumulator

Here an example:

```
val pairs = sc.parallelize(List(("prova", 1), ("ciao", 2),
                                ("prova", 2), ("ciao", 4),
                                ("prova", 3), ("ciao", 6)))

pairs.aggregateByKey(List[Any]())(
  (aggr, value) => aggr ::: (value :: Nil),
  (aggr1, aggr2) => aggr1 ::: aggr2
).collect().toMap

pairs.combineByKey(
  (value) => List(value),
  (aggr: List[Any], value) => aggr ::: (value :: Nil),
  (aggr1: List[Any], aggr2: List[Any]) => aggr1 ::: aggr2
).collect().toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

`combineByKey` is more general then `aggregateByKey`. Actually, the implementation of `aggregateByKey`, `reduceByKey` and `groupByKey` is achieved by `combineByKey`. `aggregateByKey` is similar to `reduceByKey` but you can provide initial values when performing aggregation.

As the name suggests, `aggregateByKey` is suitable for compute aggregations for keys, example aggregations such as sum, avg, etc. The rule here is that the extra computation spent for map side combine can reduce the size sent out to other nodes and driver. If your `func` satisfies this rule, you probably should use `aggregateByKey`.

`combineByKey` is more general and you have the flexibility to specify whether you'd like to perform map side combine. However, it is more complex to use. At minimum, you need to implement three functions: `createCombiner`, `mergeValue`, `mergeCombiners`.